# Datepicker disabling dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to disable dates which are stored on a database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   var dates = JSON.stringify( '<?php echo json_encode($darray); ?>');
   function BookedDates(date) {
        for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
            if (new Date(dates[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
                return [false];
            }
        }
        return [true];
    }
  //  alert(dates)
    console.log(dates);
</script>

<p>Date: <input type="date" class="datepicker2" name="date"></p>
```

The script above prints dates on a console just like that:

```
"[{\"date\":\"2016-04-02\"},{\"date\":\"2016-04-08\"},{\"date\":\"2016-04-15\"},{\"date\":\"2016-04-29\"},{\"date\":\"2016-05-07\"}]"
```

However, the problem comes when I try to disable those dates in Date picker:

```
$(function(){
    $('.datepicker2').pickadate({
        dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
        beforeShowDay:[
            BookedDates
        ]
    });
});
```

I get no error or anything on a console, those dates from array are just not being disabled, would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I've checked out a couple of similar answers. I have two suggestions. Remove the [] and simply write `beforeShowDay: BookedDates`. Also, have you tried to match the date formats in the array and the datepicker? Right now one has / and the other has - as delimiters.

Comment: Yes it's a function and I've tried matching date formats.

Comment: Have you tried any logging in the BookedDates, to make sure it is called at all? And have you tried logging the actual equals-check?

Comment: Tried using another array:

var dates = ['2016/04/15', '2016/04/30'];
Instead of:

//var dates = JSON.stringify( '<?php echo json_encode($darray); ?>');

But still nothing.

Comment: exactly which datepicker are you using? It seems like it is pickadate.js, but you seem to try to disable dates using another datepicker's library... I might be completely wrong, but that is my suspicion right now

Comment: Yes, it's a pickadate.js

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using pickadate.js, while trying to implement functionality that belongs to the JQuery UI datepicker. Those are two different libraries. You need to go to the pickadate.js api, and find a solution there:

http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/

Here is a short summary of the relevant part:

> You can disable sets of dates and then enable the entire set or
>   specific dates within those sets by the following methods:
>
> Specific dates:

```
picker.set('disable', [

  // Using a collection of arrays formatted as [YEAR,MONTH,DATE]
  [2016,9,3], [2016,9,9], [2016,9,20],

  // Using JavaScript Date objects
  new Date(2015,9,13), new Date(2015,9,24)
])
picker.set('enable', [
  [2016,9,9],
  [2016,9,13],
  new Date(2015,9,20)
])
```